# How do I get the data from a serial GPS connected to my android device?

Tags: java, android, gps, serial-port

I am working on a project where I have to connect my android device (LG G3) to a GPS with usb. I can't figure out how I can get the data out of my GPS and I do not want to use the device it's internall GPS because I need to be pretty accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to program your own USB GPS to Android, you can take a look at [USB Host](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

According to USB Host documentation:

> When your Android-powered device is in USB host mode, it acts as the
>   USB host, powers the bus, and enumerates connected USB devices. USB
>   host mode is supported in Android 3.1 and higher.

To use an USB external GPS you have to enable Android developer Options on your phone and enable using mock locations so the service (your one or a third party one) can send locations to the system "bypassing" the internal location system.

There are several apps that can transfer GPS data to your application (take a look at [Your are here GPS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agbooth.usbgps) for example. This app also lets you wath NMEA data).

Comment: Thank you for the comment sir I can definitely use this in my project